# How do you unpack a 2D array?

Tags: java

If i have a 2D array:

```
int[][] a = {
        {1, 2, 3}, 
        {4, 5, 6, 9}, 
        {7}, 
    };
```

How would i unpack it into:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7}
```

I know that you can use a for loop to do this but it seems really clunky and i was wondering if there was a better way to do this:

```
int[] b = new int[9]
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j) {
         b.append([i][j])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using streams it's easy.

- the first stream returns individual 1D arrays (the rows essentially).
- the next one flattens each of those into a single stream.
- then that stream is collected back into an array.

```
int[][] a = {
        {1, 2, 3}, 
        {4, 5, 6, 9}, 
        {7}, 
    };
int[] oneD = Arrays.stream(a).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oneD));
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7]
```

Comment: oh wow, what does `(Arrays::stream)` do?
(I don't know much java and was trying to solve some problems as i learn it)
thanks btw

Comment: It basically puts the items on pipeline to be processed by sequentially (and possibly in parrallel) by other methods.  It can make some tasks quite easy.  Check out [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more information.  It's been available since  Java 8.  Additional capabilities have been added to streams in subsequent java releases.

Answer (score 0):

Less concise, but more fast and straightforward solution of your problem:

```java
void unpack2D(int[][] arr2d) {
        int acumulator = 0;
        for(int[] innerArr: arr2d){
            acumulator += innerArr.length;     
        }
        int[] b = new int[acumulator];
        int pointer = 0;
        for (int[] innerArr: arr2d) {
            System.arraycopy(innerArr, 0, b, pointer, innerArr.length);
            pointer += innerArr.length;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
}
```